# How to add an animation each time Widget build(BuildContext context) is called in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

Here is my `build` method:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (isAuth) {
      return buildAuthScreen();
    } else if (isRegister) {
      return buildRegisterUnAuthScreen();
    } else {
      return buildUnAuthScreen();
    }
  }
```

I wanted to know if there is way to call an `animation` each time my `build` function is called and a new page is returned, so that the new page is returned with an animation.
I already know, that there is a way to do it with Animation Page route, but I only want to display an `animation` when displaying a new `buildScreen`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should not start animation when build method is called. The `build` method may be called at every frame.

To start some side effect when widget property is changed, you should use `StatefulWidget` and `initState` and `didUpdateWidget` methods.

Comment: The things is i only want to have a slide animation when calling one of those three functions which are returning a scaffold. As if i was using a animation page route, do you have a example that i can refer to ?